# django-import-export KeyError: u'CUSTOM_PRIMARY_KEY'

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

```
class ProductResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        exclude = ('pub_date','modified_date',)
        import_id_fields = ('CD-SKU',)

class ProductAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
        resource_class = ProductResource
```

The error is:

```
Line number: 1 - u'CD-SKU'
0H041501, VOL3380235300029, 3380235300029, B00FIZJI0K, 11.59, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/mws/Env/mws_prod/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/import_export/resources.py", line 434, in import_row
instance, new = self.get_or_init_instance(instance_loader, row)
File "/home/mws/Env/mws_prod/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/import_export/resources.py", line 258, in get_or_init_instance
instance = self.get_instance(instance_loader, row)
File "/home/mws/Env/mws_prod/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/import_export/resources.py", line 252, in get_instance
return instance_loader.get_instance(row)
File "/home/mws/Env/mws_prod/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/import_export/instance_loaders.py", line 31, in get_instance
field = self.resource.fields[key]
KeyError: u'CD-SKU'
```

After reading related questions, I removed the native auto generated id and used my own field as the primary. Mentioned it in the Resource class. But still its not able to import.

Would appreciate all the help. Thanks!

Comment: Please explain when this error comes up. What did you do?

Comment: It comes up when we import from a csv or an xlsx file.

Comment: Please post the code as well

Comment: Haven't written anything myself, just used this as directed https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html

Comment: How does your `Product` model look like? Does it really have `CD-SKU` field?

Comment: Yes, https://bpaste.net/show/98bfef38bede

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you just have a typo. What your model has is `CD_SKU` and you resource uses `CD-SKU`:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    CD_SKU = models.CharField(max_length = 200, primary_key=True)
```

vs

```
import_id_fields = ('CD-SKU',)
```

Change it to:

```
import_id_fields = ('CD_SKU',)
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Came across this question after troubleshooting a similar problem.

For me the fix was including the trailing comma in the `import_id_fields` declaration. Hope this helps anyone else searching for these `"Line number: 1"`  errors.